# Make every set of eight rows move into columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make every set of eight rows move into columns in Excel for example here is a set with every four rows broken into columns:

From this:
[image: Data in one column]

To this:
[image: Data in multiple columns]

I've tried this code in VBA which I've seen in a previous question found on https://superuser.com/questions/583595/move-every-7-columns-into-new-row-in-excel

```
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, cl As Range
    Dim myarray(100, 6) As Integer 'I don't know what your data is.  Mine is integer data
    'Change 100 to however many rows you have in your original data, divided by seven, round up
    'remember arrays start at zero, so 6 really is 7

    If MsgBox("Is your entire data selected?", vbYesNo, "Data selected?") <> vbYes Then
        MsgBox ("First select all your data")
    End If

    'Read data into array
    For Each cl In Selection.Cells
        Debug.Print cl.Value
        myarray(i, j) = cl.Value
        If j = 6 Then
            i = i + 1
            j = 0
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Now paste the array for your data into a new worksheet
    Worksheets.Add
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(101, 7)) = myarray
End Sub
```

However, it only seems to work with integers and not data that has both numbers and letters if I am understanding correctly.

I get an error:

```
Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch
```

Comment: How is the data before it gets to you, in csv?

Comment: `Dim myarray(100, 6) As Integer` should be `Dim myarray(100, 6) As Variant`

Comment: ^ But you could just read the entire column of data into a `Variant` array anyway and not hard-code here.

Comment: @bf2020 The data is in an Excel file and not csv. It is also in a word document. I did try to simply click on the Text to Columns button in the data tab in Excel but data needs to be separated by spaces or commas for that to work. I apologize if I misunderstood your questions

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks so much! That worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
Sub movedata()
Dim rowcounter, colcounter, rowcounter2 As Long
colcounter = 3
rowcounter2 = 1
For rowcounter = 1 To Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(rowcounter, 1).Value2 <> "" Then
        Cells(rowcounter2, colcounter).Value2 = Cells(rowcounter, 1).Value2
        colcounter = colcounter + 1
    Else
        rowcounter2 = rowcounter2 + 1
        colcounter = 3
    End If
Next rowcounter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to transpose the used range of a given sheet? This code may

```
Option Explicit

Sub transpose()
    Dim a As Integer, x As Integer
    a = 1 + Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    Cells(1, a).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, transpose:=True
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    For x = 1 To (a - 1)
        Columns(1).Delete
    Next x
End Sub
```

It works as follows:
- find the last used column and define "a" as this columnnumber + 1
- Copy the used range (where your data is)
- transpose into cells(1,a)
- select cells(1,1)
- delete this column (a-1) times

Is this what you are looking for?